# same results in arules after changing support and confidence

Tags: r, apriori, arules

Yesterday I've started experimenting with apriori and everything was working fine, i.e. I changed support and confidence and results were different depending on combination.

But today after running the same code and same dataset I'm getting 0 rules no matter which combination I'm using.

My dataset looks like this (foodmarket data):

```
Trans_Id,Product

3694728,Washington Berry Juice

3779788,Washington Berry Juice

4146666,Washington Berry Juice

4405313,Washington Berry Juice
```

etc.

My code is:

```
library('arules')
transactions <- read.transactions(file="transactions.csv",format="single",sep=",",cols=c(1,2),rm.duplicates="false")

basket_rules <- apriori(transactions, parameter = list(sup = 0.05, conf = 0.01, target="rules",minlen=2))
```

With the following results:

http://s2.postimg.org/b9k7xfq91/apriori_results1.jpg

And another one with different parameters but same result:

[image]

So, I have no idea how is that possible.

Answer (score 0):

The first screen shot is hard to read. The second one just says that there are no items in your transactions which pass the minimum support threshold and that is why you do not get any rules. Maybe there is a problem with reading the transactions. Did you try summary(transactions) first?